# Python: Point in polygon, boundary and vertex check (ray casting)

Tags: python, polygon, spatial, point, raycasting

So I have written some code to check whether a point [(x,y)] lies within a polygon [(x,y), (x,y), (x,y), (x,y)] but the code fails if the point lies on a boundary or a vertex, I need this to be classed as lying within the polygon. This is the code:

```
def areasign(poly):
    sumarea = 0
    for i in range(0, len(poly)-1):
        xi = poly[i][0]
        yi = poly[i][1]
        xj = poly[i+1][0]
        yj = poly[i+1][1]
        sumarea = sumarea + ((xi*yj)-(yi*xj))

    if sumarea == 0: return 0
    if sumarea < 0:  return -1
    if sumarea > 0:  return 1

def lineintersection(xy, ij):
    xyi = []
    xyj = []
    ijx = []
    ijy = []
    xyi.extend(xy)
    xyj.extend(xy)
    xyi.append(ij[0])
    xyj.append(ij[1])
    xyi.append(xy[0])
    xyj.append(xy[0])
    ijx.extend(ij)
    ijy.extend(ij)
    ijx.append(xy[0])
    ijy.append(xy[1])
    ijx.append(ij[0])
    ijy.append(ij[0])
    a = areasign(xyi)
    b = areasign(xyj)
    c = areasign(ijx)
    d = areasign(ijy)
    if (a!= b) and (c!=d):
        return True
    else:
        return False


def openpointfile(fname):
    p = []
    f = open(fname)
    for line in f:
        line = line.replace('POINT(', '')
        line = line.replace(')', '')
        vals = line.split(' ')
        res = map(float, vals)
        ctuple = tuple(res)
        p.append(ctuple)
        print ctuple
    f.close()
    return p

points =         openpointfile('C:/Users/Dan/Documents/Informatics/Data/Point_On_Line.txt')

def openpolygonfile(fname):
    p = []
    f = open(fname)
    for line in f:
        line = line.replace('POLYGON((', '')
        line = line.replace('))', '')
        s = line.split(',')
        poly = []
        for coord in s:
            vals = coord.split(' ')
            res = map(float, vals)
            ctuple = tuple(res)
            poly.append(ctuple)
        p.append(poly)      
    f.close()
    return p

polys = openpolygonfile('C:/Users/Dan/Documents/Informatics/Data/Polygon_On_Line.txt')

def pointinpoly(points, polys):
    infinity = tuple([100000000.0, 100000010.0])
    sum = 0
    testline = (points, infinity)
    for i in range(0, len(poly)-1):
        start = poly[i]
        end = poly[i+1]
        line = (start, end)
        l = lineintersection(line, testline)
        if l == True:
            sum = sum + 1
    if sum % 2 == 0:
        return  False
    else:
        return True

pointcount = 0
for point in points:
    pointcount = pointcount + 1
    polycount = 0
    for poly in polys:
        polycount = polycount + 1
        l = pointinpoly(point, poly)
        res = 'Point ' + str(pointcount) + ' lies within Polygon ' + str(polycount) + ' = ' + str(l)
        print l
        print (res)
```

Like i said before this doesnt work if the point lies on a boundary or a vertex, i have this function that i found on here that seems to work but i can't find a way to get it my files into the correct format for the function and to get it to iterate oer a list of polygons.

```
def point_in_poly(x,y,poly):

   # check if point is a vertex
   if (x,y) in poly: return "IN"

   # check if point is on a boundary
   for i in range(len(poly)):
      p1 = None
      p2 = None
      if i==0:
         p1 = poly[0]
         p2 = poly[1]
      else:
         p1 = poly[i-1]
         p2 = poly[i]
      if p1[1] == p2[1] and p1[1] == y and x > min(p1[0], p2[0]) and x < max(p1[0], p2[0]):
         return "IN"

   n = len(poly)
   inside = False

   p1x,p1y = poly[0]
   for i in range(n+1):
      p2x,p2y = poly[i % n]
      if y > min(p1y,p2y):
         if y <= max(p1y,p2y):
            if x <= max(p1x,p2x):
               if p1y != p2y:
                  xints = (y-p1y)*(p2x-p1x)/(p2y-p1y)+p1x
               if p1x == p2x or x <= xints:
                  inside = not inside
      p1x,p1y = p2x,p2y

   if inside: return "IN"
   else: return "OUT"
```

Any help on how to build that function into my existing code or any help on a new function that could be used to check if the point lies on the boundary of a polygon or on a vertex

Comment: could you install shapely http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html? With that, it'd be easy enough to create polylines and a PointCollection to see if individual points touch either of them.

Comment: if fact, with shapely, I don't think you'd even need to worry about the edge cases.

Comment: Its for a project of mine, we are not allowed to use shapely unfortunately as we need to use that to test it. I was thinking about using matplotlib and using paths but after looking at it for 6 hours my mind is exploding haha

Comment: That would work too. Look at my pygridgen library on github and I have a function that uses matplotlib to test for point being inside a polygon. Not sure how it handles points in the boundary, though.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I will take a look now :)